# Installing software on a separate hard drive in Linux?

Tags: linux

In Windows, I normally choose to install software on a separate hard drive, to keep the Windows installation hard drive as clean as possible. Is it possible to install Linux software on a separate hard drive, instead of installing software on the same hard drive that Linux is installed on? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: And BTW, `/opt` is one of the frequently used paths to mount the separate hard drive with the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can export the location of the software on the other drive to your path or create a shell script to start that software and add that script to your path, then you can use something like menu editor (https://askubuntu.com/questions/792067/how-to-edit-the-applications-menu-in-gnome-3) to add that application or script to the menu. Just make sure that that drive automounts on the system start to the same directory.